# what latency can i expect with azure notification hubs?

Tags: azure, push-notification, azure-notificationhub

I'm wondering what sort of latency can be expected with azure notification hubs?  the azure site just mentions 'low latency'.  are we talking minutes?  seconds?  milli-seconds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While there are all the normal caveats about general Internet traffic, Azure Notification Hubs is extremely low latency. It is governed by the Service Bus SLA, which guarantees that for each month 99.9% messages will be delivered within 5 seconds.

Now, once it gets into the various notification channels (WNS, APNS, GCM, MPNS), it may get queued up... but you can't ask for a faster way to get messages into those channels to begin with, without writing your own notification mechanism (and it is NOT a trivial task).

My experience is that thousands of messages can be sent within one second. Notification Hubs is highly parallelized and distributed. Microsoft uses it for notifications sent from the Bing/MSN News app for breaking news, and other apps, so they send hundreds of millions of messages within a minute or so.

Answer (score 2):

We are talking about ones of seconds. However, delivery time depends on network delays which is impossible to control, and also number of targeted devices does make sense - in case of million of them it may take a minute or more.

Comment: Delays can vary from country to country and from carrier to carrier. Some carriers may even completely block push messages. See for more info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff941100(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_UTDS